# Video stream from iPhone camera, retain only last 2 min of stream at all times

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am working on an iPhone app that would capture realtime video from the iPhone camera over long periods of time.  That part is fairly straightforward - the catch is that I only want the device to retain the last 2 minutes of recorded video at any time, discarding all images prior to this time period.  I'm having trouble conceptualizing how this functionality might work.  The only idea that comes to mind is to retain a stream of still images for the last 2 minutes, and discard outdated images.  Then when the user stopped the recording, these images would be compiled into a video.  It just seems really inefficient to hold on to almost 3000 images at a time.

I would love to hear any ideas for how to achieve this goal in a reasonably efficient manner.  Thank you all in advance for your input!

Best, 
James

Comment: Skip the idea with still images. You'd loose all the efficiency that video codecs have to offer. I don't think the iPhone could properly handle that amount of data. But maybe there's a compromise - recording say 10 seconds at a time, then start a new recording seamlessly and dump the oldest recording once your 2 minutes have passed... I don't know whether this seamlessness could be achieved though, or not.

Comment: @Toaster, I really like this idea.  I definitely think I can get exactly what I need from your solution.  The most recent segment might be shorter than the rest (it could be cut off early, whenever the user wants to grab the last X minutes of video) and then all segments would be concatenated and trimmed.  Perfect.  Repost this as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Done. You're welcome! I hope this will turn out to work properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the idea with still images. You'd loose all the efficency that video codecs have to offer. Plus, I don't think the iPhone can handle that amount of data properly.

But maybe there's a compromise - it may be possible to record, say, ten seconds at a time, then start a new recording seamlessly. Dump the old recordings once they become old then two minutes.

I'm not quite sure if this is possible without loosing a few frames between the recordings though.

Comment: did this work? I can't seem to start and stop a video seamlessly without losing any data in between. How did you do it?